# Change Windows Vista Domain Password

Tags: windows-vista, command-line, passwords, automation, domain

i want to change my domain password with an automation tool. since windows blocks the "ctrl+alt+del" keys to be automated or scripted, i am searching for a command line tool to call out of my automation-script. some suggestions what command line tools i should try?

Comment: Please consider the security implications of this before doing it. In order to set the password from a script, you would need to have the password in plaintext in the script, which is a really bad idea.

Comment: the script will be used to set a bunch of domainpasswords back to a default password, and it is for testing purposes anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick google nets this: 
http://teamwork.jacobs-university.de:8080/confluence/display/ircit/How+to+change+the+Windows+domain+password+from+the+command+line

`net user username * /domain`

Comment: permission denied

Comment: Needs to be done with administrator privileges. Quote from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149427: "Only administrators can change domain passwords at the Windows command prompt."